# Word for a Bad Tradition?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a pejorative synonym for *tradition*?

For example:

> The execution of "witches" during the Salem witch trials is now generally known as a ______.

Comment: [*The Salem witch trials occurred in colonial Massachusetts between 1692 and 1693 ... Eventually, the colony admitted the trials were a **mistake***](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/a-brief-history-of-the-salem-witch-trials-175162489/) I can't really argue with that assessment, but something stronger might be more appropriate *(travesty of justice?)*.

Comment: "Bad tradition" doesn't quite jive with the example given. Could you give more detail about how you'd like to use this word?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: A bad tradition is precisely what Hamlet meant by "a custom / More honoured in the breach than the observance"; too bad usage has hijacked that phrase into meaning just more *frequently* breached than observed.

Comment: Our culture(s) usually refer to "bad" traditions as *barbarisms*, in an clearly ethnocentric fashion. Not that I'm condoning the burning of "witches", but I think it applies here

Comment: Ritual. That's usually the word used for these kind of things. I know of others that are rarer, but ritual does have the subtext you are interested in.

Comment: A term such as "horror" is often used.  Doesn't imply a tradition, but does sort of imply a culture.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, ***superstition*** in the sense of *an irrational practice* works here.

> The execution of "witches" during the Salem witch trials is now
>   generally known as a ***superstition***.

M-W:

> **[superstition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superstition)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1 a** :  a belief or **practice resulting from ignorance, fear of the unknown, trust in magic or chance, or a false conception of
>   causation**

Answer (score 1):

*The execution of "witches" during the Salem witch trials is now generally known as **a stain on the history of the judiciary.***

A similar usage of the phrase by the Vatican in 2005:

> [...] The Nazis’ systematic extermination of the Jews remains “a shameful stain on the history of humanity,” says the Holy See.
>   - https://zenit.org/articles/holocaust-a-stain-on-history-says-vatican/